# fviz_cluster() not accepting for k-medoid (PAM) results

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, data-visualization, pam

Trying to visualize k-medoid (PAM) cluster results with `fviz_cluster()`, however function isn't accepting them.

It states within `?fviz_clust` "object argument = an object of class "partition" created by the functions `pam()`, `clara()` or `fanny()` in cluster package"

I've tried accessing the clustering vector through other means;

```r
pam_gower_2$clustering
pam_gower_2[[3]]
```

but then I get a separate error:

> Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

The class of pam_gower_2 is partition? As the argument expects.

```r
class(pam_gower_2)
> class(pam_gower_2)
[1] "pam"       "partition"
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```r
df_gower <- df[, c(2:21)] 
df_gower <- df_gower[, c(1:4, 11:12, 14:15, 5:10, 16:20)] 

gower_dist <- daisy(df_gower, metric="gower", type=list(ordratio=c(2:4, 6), symm=c(7:8), asymm=c(5), logratio=c(13)))

gower_mat <- as.matrix(gower_dist)
tendency_gower <- get_clust_tendency(gower_mat, 100, graph=T)
tendency_gower$hopkins_stat

fviz_nbclust(gower_mat, pam, method="wss")
fviz_nbclust(gower_mat, pam, method="silhouette")

pam_gower_2 <- pam(gower_mat, k=2, diss=T)

# all of the above functions as expected

fviz_cluster(pam_gower_2, gower_mat)
```

above line produces the following error:

> Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x),
> :'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'

Would greatly appreciate feedback/ fix, reasons as to why this doesn't work, or an alternative method for visualizing.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the documentation of `fviz_cluster`:

> data: the data that has been used for clustering. Required only when object is a class of kmeans or dbscan.

You therefore only need to pass the results of `pam` to `fviz_cluster`.

Here is a minimal example of `fviz_cluster` with `pam`:

```
library("factoextra")
library("cluster")

data("USArrests")
res <- pam(USArrests, 4)
fviz_cluster(res)
```

If you apply `pam` with a distance matrix, you have your error. A workaround is to set the `data` field of the result afterwards. Here is the modified example using a distance matrix (`diss`):

```
library("factoextra")
library("cluster")

data("USArrests")

diss = dist(USArrests)
res <- pam(diss, 4)

res$data = USArrests
fviz_cluster(res)
```

Comment: even if the result is the only argument I provide fviz_cluster() I still get the above errors, is it because it's a distance matrix and not a df or something?

Comment: So I just tried using the code you provided. If you pass pam() the parameter diss=T because you're providing a distance matrix as opposed to a df, passing the result to fviz_cluster() doesn't work ```rlibrary("factoextra")
library("cluster")

data("USArrests")
res <- pam(USArrests, 4, diss=T)
fviz_cluster(res)```

Comment: I updated the answer to handle the case where you pass a distance matrix.

Comment: Ah sweet! Thank you for that :) Totally sorted everything out

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by adding `row.names=1` when I load the dataset:

```
read.csv2("index.csv",header=T, sep=";", dec=",", row.names=1)
```